# Authoring Apple Help Book in 2019

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos

I am trying to include a help book with my Mac OS application but I am unable to do so. When I click the 'Help' menu in my application, I get the search bar and a Help menu item but I get a 'content is currently unavailable' error.

I have tried using Jekyll but I couldn't get it to work. I have also referred to the Apple Help Book documentation but it is very difficult to follow. I have also read posts on StackOverFlow but none of them seem to work currently.

I just need a simple Help Book which displays my application name and says "This is my application".

I need help in understanding the Help Book directory structure, the Title HTML content and how to integrate it to my application using info.plist.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I hope you are not going to do a Help Book just to say to your users "This is my application," but you are going to do that just as a starting point for a serious help book that can help your users understand how to best use your app. If so, this is what I do:

1. Create a folder inside your project folder called `MyAppHelp`;
2. Create a folder called `Contents` inside the latter folder;
3. Inside this folder you should create the following:

- `Info.plist`
- `PkgInfo` containing the text `BNDLhbwr` inside
- A folder called `Resources`

Thus, you should have a structure like this:

```
MyAppleHelp/
    Contents/
       Info.plist
       PkgInfo
       Resources/
           en.lproj/
              index.html
           fr.lproj/
              index.html
```

Then you can start editing your help book like any web site, using `HTML` and `css`. You can even share some of the code between your website and your help book. This structure also allows for you to have your help book localized in different languages. macOS will show the user the correct version of it automatically.

To know which keys you should use in the info.plist inside your help book, please see them [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/ProvidingUserAssitAppleHelp/authoring_help/authoring_help_book.html).

4. You should index your Apple Help book using Apple's own `Help Indexer` app, which you can download from your account at developer.apple.com (look for '`Additional tools for Xcode`' in downloads). This will create `.helpindex` files inside each folder you created inside `Contents`, which will help your user search inside your help book. **Important Update: From Mojave onwards, though, you must use the `hiutil` CLI utility to index your help pages in Spotlight help indices**. These files will have the extension `.cshelpindex` instead.
5. You should change the name of the top folder from `MyAppHelp` to `MyApp.help`. This will create a package similar to a folder when you rename a top folder with the extension .app. **From Monterey onwards you must have a `PkgInfo` file inside your help bundle to be recognized as such by the Finder.**
6. To include any changes automatically into your app you should add your help book to your `copy bundle resources` build phase.
7. Finally, do not forget to add a `Help Book directory name` and `Help Book identifier` keys in the `info.plist` of your app to tell to the OS how your help book is called or is identified.

Good luck with your Apple Help Book authoring.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try this out tomorrow. Most of the tutorials were outdated.

Comment: See my point 7. You need to add also a key to the info.plist of the main app. Otherwise this won’t work.

Comment: Yup. Thanks. I got it. I deleted the whole thing and started over.

Comment: Great question and great answer. Thanks you. I have to ask though, is there a newer way, as of March, 2020?

Comment: @DavidDelMonte Nope. The only update needed is the one I give in point 4. in boldface. The rest is still valid.

Comment: I now have the help book running. Does anyone know of an HTML/CSS template, or do I roll my own? Thanks

Comment: You can use any HTML / CSS template. Just google for it. I think you need to use HTML v.4 or later. I personally use HTML5 and CSS3 templates without a problem. Perhaps this should be turned into a new question per policy of the site.

Comment: Will somebody able to put some sample projects on GitHub and link it to it here? I am trying to get this working but was not able to get it working. @DavidDelMonte

Comment: I ended up using an alternative approach for now because: 1. My CSS skills are limited, 2. I don't want to update my app as the help changes. So, I created a web site for my app, using a template, and pointed the Help button to that site.

Comment: Anyone knows how to clear the macOS helpbook cache? So I can see updates to the help book when I do them.

Comment: @vomi Please ask a new question and I will answer you, so that other people can benefit from it. Post here where the new question is.

Comment: You are right, there it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62465800/refresh-apple-help-book-cache  I'll upvote you :-)

Comment: Unfortuantely this is lacking some serious details. Especially when you work with xcodeproj instead of using xcode to build your project targets. Maybe i should just skip it, even the OmniGroup is not using help books anymore but their own Webkit  viewer.