# Refresh Apple Help Book cache

Tags: macos, cocoa

When authoring an Apple Help Book for a macOS application, it is difficult to see the changes because macOS caches the help books for performance reasons.
You can launch your app and open the help, and you see an old version.

How can I clear this cache to immediately see the changes I make on my help books?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clear the cache of a help book you just updated, you need to install the new build of your app into the `Applications` folder. Launch the newly installed app and you should get the updated help book. That usually does the trick.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Even tough I had to wait a couple of minutes before it was actually displayed. Would be nice to have the terminal command to trigger a refresh.

Comment: I guess this is better then nothing but it still sucks.